# Issue with href attribute of <a> tag in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I am using Angular to develop Router features, so here it is my data coming from JSON as like, and below footer.html where using *ngFor is using to repeat list json list.details. But in ng-container, I`m not using any href attribute but in the image (attached) you can see there some value embedded dynamically and for this my router is not working :

```
details: {
    icon: "fa fa-google-wallet  light-blue-text",
    ref: "",
    name: "PIM",
    routeslink: "certificate"
}
```

But the problem is when router change url it is reflecting on html, which I don`t want.

[image]

```
<ul class="no-list-bullet">
    <li *ngFor="let items of list.details">
<i class="{{items.icon}}"></i> 
<a target="_blank" href="{{items.ref}}" *ngIf="items.ref !== '';else second">{{items.name}}</a>
<ng-template #second>
   <ng-container><a [routerLink]="[items.routeslink]" href="javascript:void()">{{items.name}}</a></ng-container>
   </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make link absolute

```
<ng-container><a [routerLink]="['/', items.routeslink]">{{items.name}}</a></ng-container>
```

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please mark this question as your answer so the question can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

when using routerlink you don't have to add href
You can directly use like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', items.routeslink]">{{items.name}}</a>
```